# Calling a method from within a function passed as an argument

Tags: javascript

I have a classlike thing (button). When instantiating it, I pass an onClick function as an argument to its constructor. In response to a click, I want the button instance's "deactivate()" method to be called. How do I properly refer to that method from within that function-passed-as-argument?

```
button = function(onclick){
  this.deactivate = function(){
    activeButton = null;
  }
  this.onclick = function(){onclick()};
}

var makeMainMenu = function(){
  this.multiplayerButton = new button(function(e){ 
    //onClick function of multiplayerButton:
    mainMenu.multiplayerButton.deactivate(); //HELP HERE
    selectDifficultyMenu = makeSelectDifficultyMenu();
    mainMenu.all.hide();
  });
}

mainMenu = makeMainMenu();
```

Comment: Using `onclick.call(this)` would make the button readily available in the callback as `this`. If you know jQuery, you're surely accustomed to that pattern.